# SQL find the date on have not recived any order

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, join, null

I have some tables. I just want to write query which gives me the date on which no orders were placed. I am using left joins to get the result in null but problem is: after using this I am not able to get the date.

Please help me, my code is like this:

```
SELECT DAY(o.OrderDate) AS 'HavntRecivedOrder'
  FROM Products p
 INNER JOIN Suppliers sup   ON p.SupplierID = sup.SupplierID
 INNER JOIN OrderDetails od ON p.ProductID = od.ProductID
  LEFT JOIN Orders o        ON (od.OrderID = o.OrderID
                                AND o.OrderDate BETWEEN '1/1/1997' AND '1/31/1997')
 WHERE sup.CompanyName='Tokyo Traders'
   AND o.OrderDate IS  NULL
```

Comment: You either need to dynamically construct table of dates or have permanent calendar table to be able to left join to dates from orders. What database do you use?

Comment: i am using sql server 2005,permanent calender 
query is-IN WHICH DAYS OF JANUARY 1997,THE SUPPLIER TOKYO TRADERS HAVEN'T RECIVED ANY ORDER

Comment: Please add your tables structure if possible or at least the needed columns. From your last comment I could propose a different query on my answer, just joining with Suppliers table

Comment: tables as follows
Product-productid |productname|supplierid
supplier-supplierid|company Name
orderdetails-orderid|productid|quantity
orders-orderid|Orderdate

Answer (score 0):

Please post the needed tables structures to get a better understanding of the problem.

Nevertheless from your question description I understand you want days with no orders posted, correct? Then I do not see why are you writing such complicated query. Maybe is just enough to do this...edited...

In case your Orders table has a SupplierID column then

```
DECLARE @firstdate DATETIME='19970101 00:00:00', 
        @lastdate DATETIME= '19970131 00:00:00'
DECLARE @datetable TABLE (auxDate DATE)

;WITH CTE_DatesTable
  AS
  (
    SELECT @FirstDate AS auxDate
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(dd, 1, auxDate)
    FROM CTE_DatesTable
    WHERE DATEADD(dd, 1, auxDate) <= @LastDate
  )
  INSERT INTO @datetable ([auxDate])
  SELECT [auxDate] FROM CTE_DatesTable
  OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);

SELECT auxDate AS 'HavntRecivedOrder'
      FROM @datetable auxTB
     WHERE DAY(auxTB.auxDate) NOT IN (SELECT DAY(OrderDate)
                                   FROM Orders, Supplier
                                  WHERE OrderDate = BETWEEN @firstdate AND @lastdate
                                    AND Supplier.SupplierID = Orders.SupplierID)
```

Comment: NO actually    I HAVE TOTAL 6 TABLES SO i am joining the tables to get the required data ....i did the same as you wrote but its give NULL

Comment: @user1547826 Sure it does - you want to get `DAY(o.OrderDate)` and filter is `o.OrderDate IS  NULL`. Obviously, you will get null. Please check [what is calendar table](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/sql-server-dates-table-using-tsql-cte-calendar-table.aspx).

Comment: ok thanks and i am running with another problem i have a table which consist the name and dob of employee i want to write a query which gives the age of employee in year month and day .....i am able to find the age individually in year ,month or day by using
datediff(day,column_dob,datenow()).....but what to do for year month and day

Comment: @NikolaMarkovinović is right, I did not pay attention to the NOT NULL. Edited my answer and as Nikola commented, added a CTE expression to generate all the days on the month you are looking for and then filtered the expression selecting days not present on Orders table. If your table schema is not as I supposed to be, feel free to reuse the code to fit your needs.

Comment: Edited once more as without DAY() clause on the WHERE was not returning correct values.

Answer (score 0):

Logic behind the solution:

Get the dates in January 1997 on which Tokyo Traders received order and then find the dates in January,1997 on which orders are placed with excluding the dates on which Tokyo Traders received.

Here is solution:

```
select distinct day(OrderDate) 
as 'The days in January,1997 on which Tokyo Traders havent received any orders' 
from Orders  
where OrderDate between '1997-01-01' and '1997-01-31' 
and OrderDate not in  
(select ord.OrderDate from Orders ord 
join OrderDetails ode on ode.OrderID=ord.OrderID 
join Products prod on prod.ProductID=ode.ProductID 
join Suppliers sup on sup.SupplierID=prod.SupplierID 
where ord.OrderDate between '1997-01-01' and '1997-01-31' 
and sup.CompanyName like 'Tokyo Traders')
```

Comment: This only select dates that are in Order table, what if Jan 2, 1997 is not in Order table?

Comment: According to question on which dates Tokyo traders haven't received order. So it also refers others have received orders but on those dates Tokyo haven't.